# Detect when idle ThreadPoolExecutor thread is killed

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I am using `ThreadPoolExecutor` to manage the number of threads, I can catch the event of creating a new Thread for ThreadPool via `ThreadFactory->newThread()`
But I do now know how to catch the event of killing Thread which stays idle for 2minutes as following configuration.

I hae searched a listener method but could not find.

```
public abstract class ThreadPoolEventProcessor<E>  implements ThreadFactory{

   private BlockingQueue<Runnable> taskQueue;
   private ThreadPoolExecutor executor;

   protected ThreadPoolEventProcessor(int coreThreadSize, int maxQueueSize) {
      taskQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(maxQueueSize);
      executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(coreThreadSize, coreThreadSize * 5, 2L, TimeUnit.MINUTES, taskQueue,this); 
      executor.prestartAllCoreThreads();      
   }

  public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
      return new Thread(r, getWorkerName());
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: updated my question, What exactly I want is to detect the case of event where thread is killed by executer

Comment: The executor doesn't kill the thread. The thread stops when its `run()` method returns.

Comment: keepAliveTime when the number of threads is greater than the core, this is the maximum time that excess idle threads will wait for new tasks before terminating.

Answer (score 2):

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not kill threads. It will retrieve new threads from the `ThreadFactory` and have them `run` a `Worker`. All this worker does is loop, attempting to retrieve a `Runnable` from an underlying `BlockingQueue`.

If it gets one, it invokes `run` on it.

If the `allowCoreThreadTimeOut` is `true` and you have more workers than the core amount, then the `keepAliveTime` value is used to poll that underlying `BlockingQueue`. If the `poll` returns `null`, then the worker is (potentially) removed. Some extra cleanup happens and the various method invocations are popped from the stack as the methods `return`, until eventually the `Worker#run()` method terminates and the containing thread finishes.

Nowhere in that flow does `ThreadPoolExecutor` offer any hooks for notifications.

You can poll `ThreadPoolExecutor#getPoolSize()` and `ThreadPoolExecutor#getLargestPoolSize()` for information periodically.

Answer (score 0):

In ThreadPoolExecutor class there is a set of Workers, which are runnable classes ran by Threads in the pool.

When a worker is done workerDone call back executes. And there you see a tryTerminate method being called. That is the method deciding if to terminate thread or not. You should be able to debug at that point

```
   /**
 * Performs bookkeeping for an exiting worker thread.
 * @param w the worker
 */
void workerDone(Worker w) {
    final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
    mainLock.lock();
    try {
        completedTaskCount += w.completedTasks;
        workers.remove(w);
        if (--poolSize == 0)
            tryTerminate();
    } finally {
        mainLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

---

```
/* Termination support. */

/**
 * Transitions to TERMINATED state if either (SHUTDOWN and pool
 * and queue empty) or (STOP and pool empty), otherwise unless
 * stopped, ensuring that there is at least one live thread to
 * handle queued tasks.
 *
 * This method is called from the three places in which
 * termination can occur: in workerDone on exit of the last thread
 * after pool has been shut down, or directly within calls to
 * shutdown or shutdownNow, if there are no live threads.
 */
private void tryTerminate() {
    if (poolSize == 0) {
        int state = runState;
        if (state < STOP && !workQueue.isEmpty()) {
            state = RUNNING; // disable termination check below
            addThread(null);
        }
        if (state == STOP || state == SHUTDOWN) {
            runState = TERMINATED;
            termination.signalAll();
            terminated();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this does not trigger an event

Comment: Well you need to make a bunch of configuration to achieve that. I would say configure thread pool size to one. Run two jobs concurrently and make sure keepAliveTime is low. Then there would be Two threads alive and when the job was done one of them would be killed. Why exactly you want to know where it is handled ?

Comment: What implementation (and its version) are you looking at? I don't see a `workerDone` method in Oracle JDK 8.

Comment: how can I access this workerDone method our of the ThreadPoolEventProcessor?

Comment: @mmc18 You can't. It's package private. It also no longer exists.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis oh, I did not know it did not exist anymore. God to know :)

Comment: @gomyes Note that even if it did still exist, you shouldn't depend on it. It was never a public API method.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Absolutely, although he just wants to debug